# Can you determine $n$ with oracle for primality of $n+m$ for given $m$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I haven’t studied much number theory at all, but I got asked this question by a family member who is a fan of recreational math, and I have no clue how to answer it, or even the subfield it precisely belongs to and keywords to search to find discussion of it:

Say that $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is unknown, but you have access to an oracle which, given an $m \in \mathbb N$, tells whether or not $m+n$ is prime. Is it possible to determine in finite time the value of $n$? What about for other subsets of $\mathbb N$? Is there a name for this property?

Comment: In *finite* time it seems possible, since the primes [get rarer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)... so consequently the sequence of primes following any $n$ should be sparser, and thus unique?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is indeed possible to determine $n$ in finite time. First, note that by Dirichlet's theorem, for all primes $p$, there exist infinitely many primes that are $a \bmod{p}$ for $a \in \{1, 2, \ldots, p-1\}$. Fix any prime $p > n$ and let $q_1, \ldots, q_{p-1}, q'_1, \ldots, q'_{p-1}$ be distinct primes greater than $p$ such that $q'_i \equiv q_i \equiv i \bmod{p}$. Then, we can figure out in finite time that $m + n$ is prime for $m \in \{p - n, q_1 - n, \ldots, q_{p-1} - n, q'_1 - n, \ldots, q'_{p-1} - n\}$.

First, these $2p-1$ values for $m$ cover all possible remainders modulo $p$, so one of these values $m$ must give $m + n$ being divisible by $p$, which forces $m + n = p$. Furthermore, all but one remainder (corresponding to $p-n$) occurs more than once, so we also know exactly which value of $m$ gives $m + n = p$. From here, we deduce that $n = p - m$.

**Example**: Let $n = 4$. We can use an oracle to find values of $m$ such that $m + n$ is prime until we find some prime $p$ such that the set of values of $m$ contains all remainders modulo $p$ and all but one remainder modulo $p$ at least twice. The first few values of $m$ are given by:
$$S =  \{1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 15, 19, 25, 27 \ldots\}$$
Looking at these first few values modulo $p = 5$, we see that every remainder comes at least once and every remainder except $1 \bmod 5$ comes at least twice. Thus, $n + 1 = 5$, proving that $n = 4$.

**Algorithm**: Here's an outline for how to determine $n$ efficiently in practice. Let $n = 2026$.

- We use the oracle to find the first two values of $S$. We get $S = \{1, 3, \ldots \}$. Since we have more than one element which is $1 \bmod 2$, this implies that $n \equiv 0 \bmod 2$. Now, we can ask whether $n = 2$. Indeed, if $n = 2$, then it would suffice to show that $S = \{1, 3, 5, 9, 11 \ldots \}$ and use $p = 3$. However, our oracle shows $S = \{1, 3, 13, \ldots \}$, so $n \geqslant 4$.
- Next, we look at $p = 3$. Note that $m + n$ is never divisible by $3$ when it is prime since $n \geqslant 4$. We compute $S$ until we find all but one remainder modulo $3$. Indeed, $S = \{1, 3, \ldots \}$ suffices. This tells us that $n \equiv -2 \equiv 1 \bmod{3}$, and hence, $n \equiv 4 \bmod{6}$. Now, we can ask whether $n = 4$. If $n = 4$, then it would suffice to show that $S = \{1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 15, 19, 25, 27, \ldots\}$ and use $p = 5$. This is not the case since the oracle shows $S = \{1, 3, 13, \ldots \}$. Thus, $n \geqslant 10$.
- Look at $p = 5$. Since $n \geqslant 10$, $m + n$ is never divisible by $5$ when it is prime. We compute $S$ until we find all but one remainder modulo $5$. The oracle shows that $S = \{1, 3, 13, 27, 37, 43, 55, \ldots \}$ which contains all remainders other than $4 \bmod{5}$, so $n \equiv -4 \equiv 1 \bmod 5$, implying that $n \equiv 16 \bmod{30}$. Using the same method above, one can see that $n \neq 16$, so $n \geqslant 46$.
- Look at $p = 7$ to show that $n \equiv -4 \equiv 3 \bmod{7}$, hence $n \equiv 136 \bmod{210}$. The oracle shows that $n \neq 136$, so $n \geqslant 346$. Look at $p = 11$ to show that $n \equiv -9 \equiv 2 \bmod{11}$, so $n \equiv 2026 \bmod{2310}$.
- The oracle shows that the first few values for $n$ and $2026$ indeed match. Proving $n = 2026$ is the hardest part. Pick a prime $p > 2026$, say $p = 2027$. Compute $S$ for both $n$ and $2026$ and check that they match until you have computed far enough to get all remainders modulo $2027$ and all but one twice. This proves that $n = 2026$.

Comment: How do you determine $p$ in practice, this is not clear to me ? (especially let say if $n$ is not $<100$).

Comment: @zwim I have edited my answer to include a practical algorithm.

Comment: That is nice, thx.

Comment: Thanks so much! Is there any name for this property of subsets of N? (The property that when you're given an oracle for X + M being a member of it you can determine X in finite time?)

Comment: I'm not sure. For any subset $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in S$, let $D(x) = \{y - x : y \in S, y > x\}$ and let $D(x, N) = D(x) \cap \{1, 2, \ldots, N\}$. In this notation, the subset $S$ has your oracle property iff for all $x \in S$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $y \in S$ distinct from $x$, $D(x, N) = D(y, N)$. Here's an exercise: can you find a subset $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in S$ such that for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $y \in S$ distinct from $x$ such that $D(x, N) = D(y, N)$, but such that for all $y \in S$ distinct from $x$, $D(x) \neq D(y)$?